# Many to Many relationship works one way

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a `User` and a `Quiz` models. I have many-to-many relationship defined between them in the following way:

**User model**

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quiz::class, 'subs_users', 'user_id', 'quiz_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('accepted');
}
```

**Quiz model**

```
public function subscribers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**Pivot table**

```
Schema::create('subs_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('quiz_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['user_id', 'quiz_id']);

    $table->boolean('accepted')->index();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I call `$quiz->subscribers`, it returns a collection of users as expected. However, `$user->subscriptions` **always returns an empty array**. Why is that?

---

### Edit

It seems, that replacing this line in `Quiz`

```
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
```

with

```
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'subs_users', 'quiz_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('accepted');
```

Solves the issue, but I still can't understand why the first variant does not work.

Comment: Can you provide the database structure

Comment: @sef4eg I added the other tables

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quiz::class, 'subs_users', 'user_id', 'quiz_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('accepted');
}
```

You mixed the foreign key with other key: `user_id` and `quiz_id`.

Remember when doing many to many relation that: first of foreign key's declared in `belongsToMany` is a key related to the current model.

Comment: I have swapped them, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `belongsToMany()` relationship in `Quiz` model with following:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'subs_users');
```

Solves the issue. It seems, that **when a non-standard name is used for the pivot table, both sides must explicitly state it**. In other words, `'subs_user'` pivot table name must be present in `belongsToMany()` relationship declarations in both models.